# Flex how to compile images into swf

Tags: apache-flex, flash, compilation

I have a flex project that uses bunch of images. 
When I build my project, it creates main.swf and images folder separately.

I would like to compile one swf file which should contain all images. I dont know how to accomplish this.

Here is my dir structure:

```
Main
-src (dir)
--com.main (different packages)
--images (contains images)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to embed the images in the SWF.  [More info here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html)

Conceptually something like this:

```
[Embed(source="images/logo.gif")]
[Bindable]
public var imgCls:Class;
```

In your MXML, do something like this to access it:

```
<mx:Image id="myImageRaw" source="{imgCls}"/>
```

However, your compile process should not--I believe--create an images folder.  I suspect you are using Flash Builder; which has an option to move "other files" into the bin-debug folder.  You should be able to change this in the project properties.  Bring up the Flex Compiler property page and deselect "copy non-embedded files to output folder".

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I created image folder myself. And in my application i am using this path images/loader.gif to access them. But I have one more use case where I want to display image based on user input and there are 40-50 images.

Comment: Then you better use XML described images, which is on actuall folder on your server, on on application path, then - based on the user input load checl the XML about the path to the image, and display it. This will be much easy to be managed. else - create one big file with description of each image, maybe inside array if u wish - following the "www.Flextras.com" example and it would do the job :)

Comment: @priyank Yes, if you have that many images to display, I probably wouldn't embed them all in a SWF.  Store them in some other format, such as a database, and have Flex load images as needed.